# Nested Each Loop Causing Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Hello – My question is best summarize with the intended output and the real output.  Any clue why it's doing this, using the following HTML and JS code?

**HTML Code:**

```
<h3>CATEGORY 1</h3>
<p>Item 1</p>
<p>Item 2</p>

<h3>CATEGORY 2</h3>
<p>Item 3</p>
<p>Item 4</p>

<h3>CATEGORY 3</h3>
<p>Item 5</p>
<p>Item 6</p>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery Code:**

```
$(".h3").each(function () {

  // Display H3 Text
  console.log($(this).text());

  $(this).siblings('p').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).next().is('h3') ) {

      // Display Last Paragraph Text Before <H3>
      console.log($(this).text());

      // Break the Each Loop, Go to next H3
      return false;
    }
    else {

      // Display Paragraph Text
      console.log($(this).text());
    }
  });
});
```

**Intended Output:**

```
CATEGORY 1
Item 1
Item 2
CATEGORY 2
Item 3
Item 4
CATEGORY 3
Item 5
Item 6
```

**Real (Unintended) Output:**

```
CATEGORY 1
Item 1
Item 2
CATEGORY 2
Item 1
Item 2
CATEGORY 3
Item 1
Item 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused why you worry about checking for the next h3.  If the <p> tag is within the <h3>, the nested loop will automatically handle going to the next <h3> when it reaches the end of the <p> selector.

Comment: @Jason: The `p` elements are not inside the `h3` elements. They are not even allowed there.

Comment: @Felix - Wow.  I'm a noob.  Haha, I even knew that and still asked the dumb question anyway.  Thanks for the clarification (and for not mowing me over).

Answer (score 4):

Because `siblings()` selects all siblings, all previous and all following. I think you need [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

> Get all **following** siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

---

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ucavo3)

```
$("h3").each(function () {

  // Display H3 Text
  console.log($(this).text());

  $(this).nextAll('p').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).next().is('h3') ) {

      // Display Last Paragraph Text Before <H3>
      console.log($(this).text());

      // Break the Each Loop, Go to next H3
      return false;
    }
    else {

      // Display Paragraph Text
      console.log($(this).text());
    }
  });
});
```

gives:

```
CATEGORY 1
Item 1
Item 2

CATEGORY 2
Item 3
Item 4

CATEGORY 3
Item 5
Item 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no more siblings after the last `<p>` element, I guess I'd use `.nextUntil('h3')` instead:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  $(this).nextUntil('h3').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/

If you wanted, you could even do it without the explicit calls to `.each()`

```
$("h3").text(function(i,txt) {
  console.log(txt);
  $(this).nextUntil('h3').text(function(i,txt) {
    console.log(txt);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.siblings()` function does not mean "subsequent siblings", it means "all siblings." The first two `<p>` tags are siblings of all the `<h3>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try using nextAll() instead of siblings().